# Reloading KieSession after adding/deleting Rules in KieBase

Tags: java, drools, kie

I tried to recreate a KieSession after removing a rule from the KieBase, but the removed rule is still firing.

I've created a KieBase and removed a rule using the following code:

```
    KieServices service = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem fileSystem = service.newKieFileSystem();
    KieBuilder builder = service.newKieBuilder(fileSystem);     

    ReleaseId releaseId1 = service.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId();
    KieContainer kContainer = service.newKieContainer(releaseId1);
    KieSession ksession = kContainer.newKieSession(sessionConfig);

    KieBaseConfiguration config = service.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    KieBase base = kContainer.newKieBase(config);

    base.removeRule("com.somepackage", "rule1");
    KieSession ksession1 = kContainer.newKieSession(sessionConfig);
```

But when I evaluate a Fact against the ksession1, rule1 is still firing. How do I reload the edited KieBase into a new session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a session from the modified KieBase:

```
 KieSession ksession1 = base.newKieSession();
```